# Addition in java using integer stacks

Tags: java, regex, string, stack, addition

I am working on an assignment for one of my courses where I take any size "number" in as a string that properly formatted. I use three stacks that each take in every digit as a separate numerical values. Stack one would take the first value, stack two taking the second value, and stack three having the result value pushed in and popped into a string. Finally the string is printed out to the screen.

My issue with this is my ability to "carry the one"
Let's say I add 7 and 15 in my program, my program would pop both the 7 and 5 out of stacks one and two respectively adding that together to get 12, and this is where my problem begins as you all see the one is still on the stack and I need a way to recognize that the one is actually a digit in the ten's place and so on and so forth for larger number.

Here is a posting of my entire addition method it take in command line arguments from my main method, but that's not truly important I'm trying to be as thorough as possible.

I hope I was thorough and you all understood my question I will be happy to elaborate on the subject in further detail.

```
private static void addlargeNumbers(String x, String y)throws ParseException{
    String o = x.replaceAll(",", "");
    String t = y.replaceAll(",", "");
    String r = "";
    Stack<Integer> one = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> two = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> resstack = new Stack<Integer>();


    int i = 0, j = 0;

    while(i < o.length()){
        one.push(Character.getNumericValue(o.charAt(i)));
        i++;
    }
    while(j < t.length()){
        two.push(Character.getNumericValue(t.charAt(j)));
        j++;
    }
    while(!one.isEmpty() || !two.isEmpty()){
        if(!one.isEmpty() && !two.isEmpty()){
            resstack.push(one.pop() + two.pop());

        }


        else if(one.isEmpty()){
            resstack.push(two.pop());
        }
        else{
            resstack.push(one.pop());
        }
    }
    while(!resstack.isEmpty()){
         r += resstack.pop();
    }

    if(!x.isEmpty() && !y.isEmpty()){
    System.out.printf("%s + %s = %s\n", x, y, r );
    }
    else if(x.isEmpty()){
        System.out.printf("%s = %s\n", y, r);
    }
    else{
        System.out.printf("%s = %s\n", x, r);
    }
}
```

**My Question has been answered and I've gotten it working thank you for the help.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new variable to handle the carry like

```
int  carry = 0;
```

And, then just you need to calculate and include the carry whenever required.

```
int carry=0, num1, num2, sum;
if(!one.isEmpty() && !two.isEmpty()){
    num1 = one.pop();
    num2 = two.pop();

    // Add previous carry if any. Would be `0` for first run
    sum = (num1 + num2 + carry)/10;

    // calculate and store it for next iteration
    carry = (num1 + num2 + carry)%10;

resstack.push(sum);
}
```

You also need to include logic on similar lines to the other two `if`'s you added to take care if either stack is not empty.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the help. I was able to use your logic and write something that properly added the numbers rather saying 7 + 15 = 112. Thank you sir again.

Comment: @Lemuel If you find any answer helpful, you can optionally [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146027/182516).

Answer (score 0):

make both the strings as of equal length by adding number of 0 to front small length string. and then put the characters into the stack. after that you will get the writer result

```
public void makeEqualSize(String str1,String str2){
        int num=Math.abs(str1.length()-str2.length());
        String str3="";
        if(str1.length() < str2.length()){
            for(int i=0;i < num;i++){
                str3+="0";
            }
            str1=str3+str1;
        }else{
            for(int i=0;i <num;i++){
                str3+="0";
            }
            str2=str3+str2;
        }

    }
```